# XSLT date translation from dd/mm/yyyyy to Month yyyy

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm using XSLT 1.0 and need to convert a date format from dd/mm/yyyy to Month yyyy, e.g. January 2011.

Could anyone provide a sample for this? I can find examples for XSLT 2.0 but I'm using 1.0.

Thanks,
Colin.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/workdog/archive/2007/02/08/105858.aspx, covers XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ext="metadata">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <ext:months>
    <month>January</month>
    <month>February</month>
    <month>March</month>
    <month>April</month>
    <month>May</month>
    <month>June</month>
    <month>July</month>
    <month>August</month>
    <month>September</month>
    <month>October</month>
    <month>November</month>
    <month>December</month>
  </ext:months>

  <xsl:variable name="date">23/02/2012</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(document('')
                  //month[number(substring($date, 4, 2))], 
                  ' ', 
                  substring($date, 7, 4))"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm now getting the error:

Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction property to enable it

I can't modify the way the xslt is read or written, how can I workaround the document('') declaration?

Comment: @ColinBrown, If you can't modify the way XSLT processor is executed, you can use `<xsl:choose>` like @DevNull suggested.

Answer (score 4):

I like Kirill's answer better, but here's one that doesn't use `document()`:

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
  <date>01/01/2012</date>
  <date>01/02/2011</date>
  <date>01/03/2010</date>
  <date>01/04/2009</date>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="date">
    <xsl:variable name="month">
      <xsl:call-template name="getMonth">
        <xsl:with-param name="monthNbr" select="number(substring-before(substring-after(.,'/'),'/'))"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="year">
      <xsl:call-template name="getYear">
        <xsl:with-param name="date" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <date><xsl:value-of select="concat($month,' ',$year)"/></date>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="getMonth">
    <xsl:param name="monthNbr"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=1">January</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=2">February</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=3">March</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=4">April</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=5">May</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=6">June</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=7">July</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=8">August</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=9">September</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=10">October</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=11">November</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=12">December</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="getYear">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-after($date,'/')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($year,'/')">
        <xsl:call-template name="getYear">
          <xsl:with-param name="date" select="$year"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$year"/>        
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<doc>
   <date>January 2012</date>
   <date>February 2011</date>
   <date>March 2010</date>
   <date>April 2009</date>
</doc>
```

Also, I used the template for the year instead of `substring()` to handle months/days that don't have leading zeros.

Comment: Thanks for this, would you mind explaining how I can call the function from within an existing xslt file? I've given the template a name "date" and trying this but it's not working:

`<xsl:call-template name="date">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="p:StartDate"/>`
              </xsl:call-template>

Comment: @ColinBrown - What does "not working" mean? Are you getting an error? Are you getting any output? Is `p:StartDate` a direct child of the context you're doing the `call-template` from?

Comment: Also, I have two named templates in my solution; which template did you add to your XSLT?

Comment: Hi, by not working I mean it returns blank, no error. I gave the following line the name "date" `<xsl:template match="date">` - I think that's the right one?

Comment: I'm assuming you changed `<xsl:template match="date">` to `<xsl:template name="date">` and that you added `<xsl:param name="string">` so you can pass it the value of the actual date. If that is true then the issue is most likely that you're not getting a value from `<xsl:with-param name="string" select="p:StartDate"/>`. You can try adding an `xsl:message` to your template to see what's getting passed. Something like `<xsl:message>Value of param "string" is "<xsl:value-of select="$string"/>".</xsl:message>`.

Comment: You can also update your question with your template(s) and sample XML or email it to me (address in my profile) and I can take a closer look.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've modified what you provided and managed to get it working, thank you! I won't post the code here, I think your solution is more useful for people with the same issue than mine.

Answer (score 0):

obviously its not possible with XSLT 1.0 alone .. for a similar Q I suggested scripting .. (C#) ..

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <date>02/10/2012</date>
  <date>2/9/2012</date>
</root>
```

Sample XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:cs="urn:cs">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="cs">
    <![CDATA[
        private static string[] formats = new string[]
        {
        "dd/MM/yyyy",
        "dd/M/yyyy",
        "d/M/yyyy",
        "d/MM/yyyy",
        "dd/MM/yy",
        "dd/M/yy",
        "d/M/yy",
        "d/MM/yy"
        };


          public string date_conv(string date1)
         {
             DateTime dDateTime;
             DateTime.TryParseExact(date1, formats, new global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), global::System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dDateTime);
             return(String.Format("{0:MMMM yyyy}", dDateTime));
          }
    ]]>
  </msxsl:script>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="date">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="cs:date_conv(.)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Resulting Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <date>October 2012</date>
  <date>September 2012</date>
</root>
```

The script may reside in a same file (like I have it in my sample XSLT code) or if the code triggering XSLTransformation is C# then move the same code in the calling place :)

Comment: "obviously its not possible with XSLT 1.0 alone"?

Comment: @DevNull, :) well I assumed date to be in the above mentioned `formats` .. this code uses tryparse method which can digest and convert it to desired format .. where as your method can only read "dd/MM/yyyy" .. well I take my words back! not possible isn't a good choice of word :)